# What's the right notations for the inverse hyperbolic functions? ar_ or arc_?

Tags: notation

To notate the inverse hyperbolic functions, we may see two different prefixes: **ar_** and **arc_**. The former stands for **AREA**, while the latter for **ARC**. Thus, the latter seems not reasonable, since it is likely to be a sort of **false analogy** with the notations for the inverse trigonometric functions.

But the famous website [WolframMathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHyperbolicSine.html) just use the latter. Why is it? Just "Make the Same Mistake"?